# How pass variable addresses in inline gcc assembler (linux)

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

I am using inline assembler in gcc (under Linux).
I've wrote this simple program:

```
           char *str="hello world";

           int main(int argc, char *argv[]
          {
            ...
                asm("mov %0,  %%rcx" 
                       : 
                       : "g" (str));
            ...
          }
```

I am using this strange syntax to write the address of the string in the rcx register.
But when i disassemble the binary, i see that the data is first transfered in rax, then in rcx. As you can imagine, this can introduce some bord effects in my program...
When i was young, i used to write something like that:

```
          asm("mov _str, rcx")
```

but it does not work on Linux gcc... why ?

Comment: Using GCCs inline assembler can be problematic to use if your new to it (and can cause issues in for experienced users). First off unlike MSVC inline assembler - GCC's inline doesn't actually know anything about the instructions inside the template except that it does textual substitutions You need to tell it what the inputs are, what the outputs are and if you destroy any other registers not listed in the output operands they need to be in the clobber list. For this to even work you'll need to assign _RCX_'s value to a variable with an output constraint.

Comment: The question would be why you are trying to put the address of string into RCX? Seem slike this might be an XY problem. What is it you are really trying to achieve with inline assembler? If it can be done in _C_ then it should be done there.

Comment: If you look at the output of GCC with no optimizations (like `-O0`) you'll find a lot of unnecessary overhead (extra loads and stores moving data back and forth unnecessarily).

Comment: Thanks. There is not i simpliest method? I just want to load a memory address in rcx. I want to make a syscall and i need to put a memory address in this register as a parameter

Comment: GCC inline assembler is not trivial to use (and fraught with pitfalls if you don't get it right). You can create inline assembler and it may appear to work, but later as the program expands incorrect inline assembler can introduce hard to find bugs.. In fact if you are new and you really want to use assembler, I'd recommend writing the function that does the syscall in pure assembler and link that assembler function to your _C_ code.

Comment: The GNU _C_ library has a syscall function http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/System-Calls.html  . Maybe avoid the inline assembler altogether?

Comment: I want to make a program that does not include anything. A sort of shellcode

Comment: If the bulk of your shell code is being written in assembler, why not just code it in assembler directly rather than inline it in _C_?

Comment: Because it is simpliest to work in c. I want to create all basic functions i need (fwrite, etc..) then write all in c

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>           char *str="hello world";
> ...
>           asm("mov _str, rcx")
> ```
>
> but it does not work on Linux gcc... why ?

The error messages of gcc should tell why. The most probable causes are

- no underscore must be prepended to the global variable name
- a percent sign must be prepended to the register name

Something like `asm("mov str, %cx")` works.